# Saving object reference of class in Session or declare as static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Let´s say I have a class like this:

```
class Test{

   private string status;

   public Test(){

      //Do some processing. After processing is done assign

    status = "processdone_uniqueidhere";

      }    
}
```

Now, in my asp.net application I need to periodically check status using a timer for a value when the processing is done.

Basically, I can store the reference of the class "Test" in session such as:

```
Test t = new Test();
Session["uniquesession"] = (Test)t;
```

This was, in the timer, I can retrieve the instance of the class from the session and check for the value of status:

```
Test t = (Test)Session["uniquesession"];

string value = t.status;
```

I´m not able to store the reference in a ViewState even if I declare the class as [Serializable]. Not sure why. Works with session though.

The other method is to declare the class as static and declare the variable status as static and public and check the value like this:

```
string value = Test.status;
```

Which way is most stable and which way is bad practice?

Comment: If you want to share the object across all requests you have you make it static, but i strongly recommend to put it in the `Session`. If you want to share it across all users you could also use the `Cache`.

Comment: well I have about 12 different classes like that. Storing all of them in Session will hurt my scalability and use a lot of server resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is specific to the current user, use Session.

If it's global, use Cache or a static member.

Comment: It is specific to the current user. Is it wrong to use static anyway?

Comment: @Dimo: Then it's incorrect to use cache or static variables. Use session or a database.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way. It should be static if it needs to be shared, and it should NOT be stored in the session. The session is for volatile information that maintains state per user, not for something to be shared across users. Even more importantly, if you ever move to an out-of-process session, your class will be serialized and deserialized regularly, and this will likely reset or mess with your timer. Not to mention when the session expires, the class is gone.

Make it static, but more imortantly, think long and hard about what the goal of the class is, and why it needs to exist. Put transient, volatile data in the Session, not classes with logic.

Comment: It will NOT not need to be shared across users. It is per user basis.

Comment: If it is per user basis, is it still ok to do static?

Comment: No, a static is one instance shared. If you need something per user, Session MAY be the way to go, but things like Timers will make it very tricky for you.